# relationship between male gender and age variance

Tags: regression, logistic, variance, age

I would like to ask for help on the next question:
In a logistic regression model, the male gender increased the risk of acut myocardial infarction at older age population, but in the young age population we did not get any significant difference since there was much less age variance here. What is the relationship between male gender and age variance?

Comment: If very few men have severe heart attacks at a young age, you may not have sufficient data to answer the question.